# Representing money data in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a use case where it would be useful to have a node in Neo4j with a property representing committed spend in UK pounds, i.e. a monetary value. What is the best way to handle this in Neo4j? Do I need to round all values to the nearest pound and store as a long? I could treat as pence, i.e. multiply the value by 100, and keep fidelity in amounts? Any other ideas?

Additional info: I am using Talend studio for big data to import data. The source is MS SQL Server where the data is stored as the data type money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing further details on what you do with the money values stored in your application it's hard to give a well grounded answer.

If the focus is on math, you might be better off using long and store the amount in pence, if the focus is on ease of use for e.g. displaying data, I'd prefer to have double/float values.

The currency should go into a secondary property. Alternatively you can also model this via labels. So a node representing 100 GBP would have a property amount=100.00 and a label "GBP" in this case.

Comment: who cares about accuracy when it comes to money - we're living in a world of debt. sorry for OT

Comment: lol :P people buying products may care if you calculate the shopping cart incorrectly! (but yeah, often it doesn't matter)

Comment: Yes, a bit vague I know - it is just I have users who want to do everything! :) I guess I am really interested in the best way to achieve both and your answer confirms my thinking. Thanks. I really wanted to check that I am not missing a trick and that there is another way...! For my scenario using nodes for the amounts is not going to work but I can see that it would for some uses.